Are those S.M.A.R.T. errors indicate some serious HDD health issues and should I suspect that those S.M.A.R.T. data are tampered?
I've just bought some used hard drive. Using smartctl tool, I found that the Device Error Count value is 16566. Displayed number of reallocated sectors is zero, but should I worry that someone tampered S.M.A.R.T. data or something?
I've read that those errors could be related to bad power supply, but not mandatory. Can some answers be found based on most recent 24 errors which are contained in device's log and listed below?

Long S.M.A.R.T. test completed without errors
One-pass badblocks testing didn't find any bad secotr

smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.8.11-300.fc40.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Blue
Device Model:     WDC WD40EZRZ-22GXCB0
Serial Number:    ...
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2be108aef
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jun 18 10:24:37 2024 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (44880) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 477) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR-K   200   200   051    -    0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS--K   180   163   021    -    5991
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    167
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   200   200   140    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         -OSR-K   200   200   000    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   094   094   000    -    4683
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    166
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    121
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   165   165   000    -    106806
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   122   091   000    -    28
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   200   200   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   200   200   000    -    5
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   ---R--   200   200   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      6  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa0-0xa7  GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xa8-0xb6  GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb7       GPL,SL  VS      56  Device vendor specific log
0xbd       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL     VS      93  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (6 sectors)
Device Error Count: 16566 (device log contains only the most recent 24 errors)
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 16566 [21] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 61 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 04 e0 00  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  2f 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 04 e0 00  1d+17:01:42.536  READ LOG EXT
  b0 00 d0 00 01 00 00 00 c2 4f 00 a0 00  1d+17:01:42.533  SMART READ DATA
  b0 00 da 00 01 00 00 00 c2 4f 00 a0 00  1d+17:01:42.529  SMART RETURN STATUS
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+17:00:13.233  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:57:26.796  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 16565 [20] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 61 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  Device Fault; Error: ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:53.572  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:52.569  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:51.555  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:50.556  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:49.555  READ DMA EXT

Error 16564 [19] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 61 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  Device Fault; Error: ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:52.569  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:51.555  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:50.556  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:49.555  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:49.554  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 16563 [18] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 61 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  Device Fault; Error: ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:51.555  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:50.556  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:49.555  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:49.554  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:49.371  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 16562 [17] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 61 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  Device Fault; Error: ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:50.556  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:49.555  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:49.554  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:49.371  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:48.836  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 16561 [16] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 61 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  Device Fault; Error: ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:53:49.555  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:49.554  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:49.371  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:53:48.836  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  b0 00 d0 00 01 00 00 00 c2 4f 01 a0 00  1d+16:53:48.827  SMART READ DATA

Error 16560 [15] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 61 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  Device Fault; Error: ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:52:51.226  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:52:50.817  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:52:50.227  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:52:49.212  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:52:48.213  READ DMA EXT

Error 16559 [14] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 61 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  Device Fault; Error: ABRT 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:52:50.227  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:52:49.212  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:52:48.213  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00  1d+16:52:47.215  READ DMA EXT
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00  1d+16:52:47.213  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 19748 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 19748 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 00 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.071  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  b0 da 00 00 4f c2 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.034  SMART RETURN STATUS
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.033  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  b0 d8 00 00 4f c2 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.033  SMART ENABLE OPERATIONS

Error 19747 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 00 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.033  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  f5 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.032  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK
  ef 66 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.032  SET FEATURES [Disable revert defaults]

Error 19746 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 00 00 00 00 a0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  f5 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.032  SECURITY FREEZE LOCK
  ef 66 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.032  SET FEATURES [Disable revert defaults]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:43.886  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 19745 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4255 hours (177 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 00 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 66 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:45.032  SET FEATURES [Disable revert defaults]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   1d+16:50:43.886  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 19744 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2737 hours (114 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 61 00 00 00 00 a0  Device Fault; Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00   6d+21:07:21.597  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00   6d+21:07:20.590  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 a0 00   6d+21:07:19.584  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       258 (0x0102)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    27 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     27/27 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     22/59 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Vendor specific:
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/60 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           -41/85 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    478 (452)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
...

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4             166  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4            4683  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6      7653733743  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6        29975086  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6       128579334  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6         6179985  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x01  0x038  6      3973898112  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x03  0x008  4            4668  ---  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
0x03  0x010  4             395  ---  Head Flying Hours
0x03  0x018  4          106928  ---  Head Load Events
0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
0x03  0x028  4               2  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
0x03  0x030  4               0  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
0x03  0x038  4               0  ---  Number of Realloc. Candidate Logical Sectors
0x03  0x040  4             121  ---  Number of High Priority Unload Events
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4           85277  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              28  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1              33  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1              33  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              59  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              25  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              42  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1              28  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1              36  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1              31  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              60  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4           24305  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4           21011  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  2            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  2            0  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            1  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000d  2            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x8000  4          254  Vendor specific


You can't really tamper with SMART data, but lots of errors doesn't mean the drive is bad perse. For a second-hand drive, this is to be expected, question is, how much did you pay for the drive. The drive could work well for more than a year, and it can fail out of the blue. I should not store critical data on it that is not backed up somewhere else. Do note, if the harddisk was in a write-cycle and the PC was turned of by holding the powerbutton, the harddisk will log that as an error too.

@LPChip - Thanks! Don't worry, I plan to use this HDD as an off-site backup and that's why I decided to buy a second-hand HDD. All other disks I have were bought brand-new (including the one for a regular backup). But even the most heavily used one disk I have has zero of those errors. And there were power losses and power button resets during all these years. I just think that this amount of errors is too big and don't understand really those log entries.  The price was reasonable for a second-hand drive, but assuming that it works fine, ofc :)

I would not be surprised if a powerfailure would instantly trigger 4 or 5 errors for one event. But it is also possible that the drive was connected with a faulty cable, causing read errors. These would also be logged as errors. As long as SMART doesn't say the drive is actually failing, and you don't use it for critical things, there's no need to really worry. Just keep in mind that the drive may fail one day out of the blue.

Multiple hardware errors don't necessarily indicate a bad drive, only that at the power on hours they occurred at there was a hardware issue. What is concerning about the S.M.A.R.T output is the lack of self-tests - there are none. To determine if the drive is safe to use, run a long S.M.A.R.T test, which will take half a day or so to complete, and if it completes successfully, the drive is likely fine to use barring no additional hardware errors: smartctl -t long /dev/<disk>. On HDDs, it's recommended to run S.M.A.R.T short tests weekly and long tests bi-weekly, reviewing results afterwards

@LPChip How would a dirty shutdown cause S.M.A.R.T hardware errors to populate? A bad SATA/SAS cable, or EMI of the SATA/SAS cable, can cause AHCI and CamControl errors within an OS, but AFAIK, the only thing that registers as a S.M.A.R.T error is an actual hardware error on the drive that prevented data from being read or written (drive/case gets bumped, drive/case is picked up while spinning, a spec of dust that for whatever reason wasn't flung off the platters and into the air filter during read or write, etc.)

@JW0914 if a drive is in the middle of a write and an unexpected power loss occurs, a drive equipped with SMART has something to flag that it happened, so it can write to its log upon next power-on. It is doesn't mean this error is bad, but it is logged, similarly that if you have a faulty powercable for the drive, and the drive unexpectedly loses power, it will also be logged the same way. For Mechanical drives, it even has stuff build-in to ensure that the head is parked at that event.

@JoepvanSteen do you have any documentation on how to tamper with SMART values? I was under the impression that they are in a protected memory segment of the controller that you can only read from, not write to.

@JW0914 Before I saw your comment, I run short SMART test which passed. Then I decided to run badblocks (one-pass destructive write with random pattern) instead of long SMART test. 38% completed so far with no problems reported...

@JoepvanSteen Thanks. But that is still only reset, not change values?

@LPChip It certainly used to be possible for some drives - see How to reset SMART results

@R2-D2 A long S.M.A.R.T test is required, short tests are not sufficient to determine if a drive is good or not. Even on a brand new HDD that's just been opened, it's recommended to do a burn-in (a long S.M.A.R.T test) prior to even formatting the drive.
